# Draw on QWidget

Tags: qt, inheritance, drawing

**How can I draw on QWidget(element on my form)?**

I read many tutorials but none of them covers what I really have to do(draw some Rect on QWidget) .

I made a class MyFigure which inherits from QWidget, and at even paint wrote some code to draw a rectangle.
Then, in my Form Create I create MyFigure object, and just show it.

IT DOESN"T WORK!!!

Comment: I removed your contact information from your question. You can write those in your profile. It is also not in the spirit of stackoverflow to solve things outside of here. Share your code in a minimal sort of way so people can see and understand what you are doing and answer you here on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene are good for painting, but if you want to draw on QWidget you need to reimplement paintEvent:

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPaintEvent>
class Widget : public QWidget
{
public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent=0);

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
};

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
}

void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter;
    painter.begin(this);
    painter.fillRect(event->rect(), Qt::white);
    QWidget::paintEvent(event);
    painter.end();
}
```

This code will fill your widget with white color.

Comment: Your code is not compileable 
Drawing/myfigure.cpp:3: error: undefined reference to `vtable for myFigure'

Do you have any ideas how we could solve this?

Comment: @fiter Oh, forgot () in "painter.end();", sry.

Comment: @fiter Also, if you write this in one file(class declaration must be in *.h, and implementation in *.cpp), you will have troubles with Q_OBJECT macro. Just find out it.

Comment: Better to do it with using [QGraphicsScene](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html) and [QGraphicsView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html).

Comment: I know that, but is it possible to do it this way? Oh, by way can I draw widgets as objects in QGraphicsScene? If it's possible , then EVERYTHING is perfect, and I won't need this way of drawing (inheriting QWidget) anymore...

Comment: @fiter Qt have such thing, like [QGraphicsWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicswidget.html) that is base class for Widget on QGraphicsScene, but i have no expirience with it, sry)

Comment: Notes: 1. `painter.end()` is unnecessary. This is not JAVA: RAII is a thing :) 2. Since the year is 2016 - prefer `override` to `Q_DECL_OVERRIDE`. 3. In the same vein, `parent = nullptr`, not `parent = 0`. 4. Calling `QWidget::paintEvent` is unnecessary. The widget composition engine does background painting etc., not `QWidget::paintEvent`

Comment: And to add to Monica's notes.  If the constructor and and paint event code is placed immediately after their declarations and not defined separately, then this can all be put in a header file.