# how can i create or achieve a chart like this in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

[image]

I want to create a chart like this in qt. I already searched and can not find a way to do it.

I also can not find a way to customize Barchart and look like this in Widget Based Applications

Comment: Did you take a look to https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qtcharts-overview.html ?

Comment: Yes, I did. but it did not help

Comment: Does this help: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qbarseries.html ?

Comment: I already read this documentation. Maybe there's something I have not seen yet. but this documentation has nothing that tells you how to change the shape of the bar or something like that

Answer (score 1):

Easy in QML!

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Rectangle
{
    width: 600
    height: 300

    ListModel
    {
        id: dataModel
        ListElement { label: "C.A"; value: 37 }
        ListElement { label: "C.B"; value: 58 }
        ListElement { label: "C.C"; value: 16 }
        ListElement { label: "C.D"; value: 5 }
        ListElement { label: "C.E"; value: 95 }
        ListElement { label: "C.F"; value: 10 }
        ListElement { label: "C.G"; value: 27 }
        ListElement { label: "C.H"; value: 2 }
    }

    Rectangle
    {
        height: 4
        width: layout.width
        anchors.top: layout.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: layout.horizontalCenter
        color: "#bbbdbe"
    }
    RowLayout
    {
        id: layout
        width: 400
        height: 200
        spacing: 0
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Repeater
        {
            id: rpt
            property int barWidth: layout.width / count
            model: dataModel
            delegate:
                Rectangle
                {
                    width: rpt.barWidth
                    height: layout.height
                    color: "transparent"

                    Rectangle
                    {
                        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                        width: 3
                        height: (parent.height * value) / 100
                        color: "#448bbe"

                        Rectangle
                        {
                            color: "#448bbe"
                            radius: width / 2
                            width: 8
                            height: 8
                            anchors.top: parent.top
                            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                        }
                    }
                    Text
                    {
                        y: parent.height + 3
                        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                        text: label
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: I know it's easy to do with QML but I'm doing my application in Widget Based Applications.

Do you know of any way to do without using QML or integrating QML with Widget Based Applications?

Comment: Then why haven't you specified it in your question ? Would have saved me some time, damn it. QML IS Qt.

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP didn't specify he wants a solution for a Qt widgets based application [he did after editing the question], the answer is:

Create your own QWidget class. Override the [paintEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent) and paint in it with a QPainter. I think there's plenty of examples if you google it.

Like this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-painting-basicdrawing-example.html

Or this: http://programmingexamples.wikidot.com/qt-qpainter-example

Or this: [Draw on QWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40264651/draw-on-qwidget)

Comment: thank you. I'll see if that's what I need.
but it is possible to use QPainter to change the shape of a QBarSeries?

Answer (score 0):

You can go for Custom [QQuickPaintedItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickpainteditem.html) here you can find an [Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-tutorials-extending-qml-example.html).

Comment: I'm doing my application in Widget Based Applications. Do you know of any way to do without using QML or integrating QML with Widget Based Applications?